# Best way to store ROE in C#

Tags: c#

I want to save Rate of Exchange of all currencies corresponding different base currency. What is the best and efficient type or struct to save the same. Currently i am using

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>>();
```

Thanks in advance. Please suggest

Comment: Looks good, do you have any problems?

Comment: just looking for any other better option than dictionary.

Comment: Please describe your metric for "better". I tend to optimise for readability before anything else.

Comment: Note from someone working in bank industry for 5 years: exchange rates are better be designated as FX rates or plainly "Exchange rates". RoE associates with Return on Equity first, Rules of Engagement second, Records of Employment third - and I haven't ever heard it being applied to exchange rates. So there's much ambiguity. I understand this might be your employer's stable terminology, but if you can influence it - all for the better.

Comment: strings are bad do a Enum with the possible currencies it not only is more performant (int vs string) but less error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically I use a variation of the following class.

```
public ForexSpotContainer : IEnumerable<FxSpot>
{
     [DataMember] private readonly Dictionary<string, FxSpot> _fxSpots;

     public FxSpot this[string baseCurrency, string quoteCurrency]
     {
         get
         {
             var baseCurrencySpot = _fxSpots[baseCurrency];
             var quoteCurrencySpot = _fxSpots[quoteCurrency];

             return baseCurrencySpot.Invert()*quoteCurrencySpot;
         }
     }

    public IEnumerator<FxSpot> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _fxSpots.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

}
```

I tend to then create a `Money` class and a `FxSpot` class then create +-*/ operators for the Money and FxSpot classes so that I can do financial calculations in a safe way.

EDIT: I my experience, when working in financial systems, I have always had issues with code like this

```
decimal sharePriceOfMsft = 40.30m;
decimal usdEur = 0.75m;
decimal msftInEur = sharePriceOfMsft * usdEur;
```

Since it always takes a few second for me to check if I should multiply the spot or divide.

The problem is compounded when I have to use Forex Crosses, such as JPYEUR or EURJPY etc, and hours were lost to subtitle bugs from close Forex Spots.

Also of consequence is the dimensional analysis of equations. When you multiple lots of numbers together and you expect a Price, are you sure you didn't mess up a multiple/divide. By creating a new class for each unit, you have a little more compile time error checking that can ultimately save you seconds for each line of code you read (which in a many thousand line library will add up to hours very quickly).

Comment: can you explain me more that how can I use that or what benefits I'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see big problem with your approach, if not

> 1) use some custom 3rd party in memory DB ([redis](http://redis.io/) like) . But may reveal too combersome for your case.
>
> 2) derive from your type

```
public class MyCustomHolder : Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, decimal>> {
}
```

So avoid that long and confusing definitions in the code, and bring more semantics to
your code reader and yourself.

Comment: @Rohit: so your solution makes sence for your case and scales well? So you don't have a problem.